# Как выровнять содержимое всплывающего окна на colorBox-е по высоте изменяющегося сожержимого?

Tags: jquery, валидация

Использую для всплывающей формы плагины [colorBox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) и [jQueryValidate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/).

Проблема заключается в том, что при возникновении ошибки валидации, появляется сообщение об ошибке и в окне появляется вертикальный скролл. Как сделать так, чтобы размеры окна подстраивались динамически под высоту содержимого?

Сайт: [http://remholod.ks.ua](http://remholod.ks.ua/)

HTML:

```
<div id="request-form">
    <div class="repair">Ремонт холодильников</div>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Имя">
        <input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Телефон">
        <button>Оставить заявку</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#send-request").colorbox({inline:true, href:"#request-form"});

$('#request-form form').validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
        },
        phone: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 6
        }
    },
    messages: {
        name: {
            required: "Введите имя",
            minlength: "Нужно больше символов"
        },
        phone: {
            required: "Введите телефон",
            minlength: "Нужно больше символов"
        }
    },
    success: "valid", submitHandler: function() {

            $("#request-form form").submit(function() { //устанавливаем событие отправки для формы
                    var form_data = $(this).serialize(); //собераем все данные из формы
                    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST", //Метод отправки
                    url: "mail.php", //путь до php фаила отправителя
                    data: form_data,
                    success: function() {
                           //код в этом блоке выполняется при успешной отправке сообщения
                           alert("Благодарим за заявку. Ваше сообщение отпрвлено!");
                    }
                });
            });  

    }
});
```

[image: скриншот окна]

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать `colorbox.resize();` при ошибки валидации. В Вашем случаи выглядеть это должно примерно так:

```
.......
 rules: {
        name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
        },
        phone: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 6
        }
    },
    invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
        $.colorbox.resize();       
  },
    messages: {
......
```

Много полезного можно обнаружить в **[документации](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/)**